# How should I structure my GWT integration tests when using Maven?

Tags: gwt, maven, integration-testing

I'm using Maven to build a GWT application. We are using a parent module with several sub-modules in Maven. We decided to make a separate module for integration tests, because it seemed like a hassle to keep integration tests separate from unit tests in the same module. But, when we tried to run GwtTestCase tests from the separate maven module, it proved to be problematic; specifically, we couldn't find an easy way to get the test to see the entry point to our application in Eclipse or in Maven.

Is there a good way to structure GWT integration tests when using Maven? Is the best option to leave them in the GUI module and try to separate the integration tests from the unit tests using a maven profile?

Answer (score 0):

We don't extract integration tests into separate module

In our project we make it this way:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nointegration</id>
      <properties>
        <integration.tests.includes>none</integration.tests.includes>
      </properties>
    </profile>
...
</profiles>
```

When we don't want to run integration tests:

```
mvn clean install -Pnointegration
```

so only usual, non-integration test was runned